# Parsing XML code and create table to length tag

Tags: javascript, html, xml

I've created a code that parsing a XML structure in a simple mode.
The following code:

```
function crea(l) 
{
    for(var i=0; i<l.length;i++)
    {
        var nome_nodo = l[i].getElementsByTagName("nome");
        var nome = nome_nodo[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
        var cognome_nodo = l[i].getElementsByTagName("cognome");
        var cognome = cognome_nodo[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
        var materia_nodo  = l[i].getElementsByTagName("materia");
        var materia = materia_nodo[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
        var tipo_nodo = l[i].getElementsByTagName("tipo");
        var tipo = tipo_nodo[0].firstChild.nodeValue;   
    }
}
```

**Variables definitions**

l: is the parameter of the XML node "*dipendente"*
nome_nodo: read the first occurrency *"nome"* in the XML file
nome: get the first Child of *nome_nome*

Now I want create an html table that have a dinamic rows, in particular if I've 3 elements in the XML, the code making a table with 4 rows (default header and 3 rows with the parameter in the previous variable declared).

**Example**

read 3 contents, table result:

Row (0) => default row
Row (1) => parameter read
Row (2) => parameter read
Row (3) => parameter read

**XML Structure**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<istituto>
    <dipendente categoria="Professore">
        <nome>Gennarino</nome>
        <cognome>Divi</cognome>
        <materia>Sistemi e reti, tec.prog.sist.inf.te.</materia>
        <tipo>Professore</tipo>
    </dipendente>   
    <dipendente categoria="Professore">
        <nome>Luca</nome>
        <cognome>Salza</cognome>
        <materia>Sistemi e reti, gest.prg.organ.d'imp,tec.prog.sist.inf.te</materia>
        <tipo>Professore</tipo>
    </dipendente>   
</istituto>
```

I know the mode for create a table, algorithm like:

```
function creaTabella()
{
     var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]; 
     var tabella = document.createElement('table');
     var tbdy = document.createElement('tbody');          

     for(var i = 0; i < 4; i++) 
     {
         var tr = document.createElement('tr');              

         for(var j = 0; j < 8; j++)                             //columns
        {
             var td = document.createElement('td');                 
             tr.appendChild(td);                            
        }
        tbdy.appendChild(tr);
    }
}
```

the problem is how pass the parameter reading by parser code, because this table have a default structure, but I need a dinamic table that create rows with the numbers of elements readed in the XML file.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: If I understand the question, you want to read some XML, and write out rows of data in an HTML table based on the matching data found in the XML?

Comment: Yes, you have understand correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say you have a default structure, I'm guessing you have an HTML table that is either already on the page, or one that you need to add to the page, but in either case it has fixed columns matching the child elements of your XML. In that case, you need only parse the XML, loop through the rows of the XML and add rows to your table. As such, I built the following example.

```
var xml = '<?xml version="1.0"?>' + 
'<istituto>' + 
'   <dipendente categoria="Professore">' + 
'    <nome>Gennarino</nome>' +
'        <cognome>Divi</cognome>' +
'        <materia>Sistemi e reti, tec.prog.sist.inf.te.</materia>' +
'        <tipo>Professore</tipo>' +
'    </dipendente>' +
'    <dipendente categoria="Professore">' +
'        <nome>Luca</nome>' +
'        <cognome>Salza</cognome>' +
'        <materia>Sistemi e reti, gest.prg.organ.d\'imp,tec.prog.sist.inf.te</materia>' +
'        <tipo>Professore</tipo>' +
'    </dipendente>' +
'</istituto>';


var parser = new DOMParser();
var xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(xml, "text/xml");

var rows = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("dipendente");
var tableBody = document.querySelector("tbody");

createTabella(tableBody, rows);

function createTabella(table, xmlRows){
   for (var i=0; i < xmlRows.length; i++){
    var tr = document.createElement("tr");
    tr.appendChild(buildTD(xmlRows[i], "nome"));
    tr.appendChild(buildTD(xmlRows[i], "cognome"));
    tr.appendChild(buildTD(xmlRows[i], "materia"));
    tr.appendChild(buildTD(xmlRows[i], "tipo"));
    tableBody.appendChild(tr);
  } 
}

function buildTD(parentElement, elementName){
  var el = parentElement.getElementsByTagName(elementName)[0];
  var td = document.createElement("td");
  td.textContent = el.textContent; 
  return td;
}
```

And here is a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/90Je3dCoyJ7M3pa0bcN2?p=preview) showing how it works.

Comment: Thank you very much, one question: is possible pass a directory of the file instead of variable xml?

Comment: You could make an ajax request for the XML, yes. You'll probably want to use a library like jQuery to do that.

Comment: I updated the plunker to show getting the XML from the server using jQuery.